# In Laravel 5.4 how do i call multiple model method in a controller

Tags: laravel-5

I can't access model methods that is defined in different model class. 
I tried this way

```
use App\Models\Admin\Test;
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    { 
       Test::get_banner_category();// working
       Banner::get_banner_category_all(); // not working
    }
}
```

I tried with Model binding like this way but failed

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {


        parent::boot();

        Route::model("banner", 'App\Models\Admin\Banner');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to `use` the model.

```
use App\Models\your\path\to\Banner;
```

If that's not working, please add your Banner model code here.

Does it have a `public static function get_banner_category_all()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
use App\Models\Admin\Banner;
```

Full Example :

```
use App\Models\Admin\Test;
use App\Models\Admin\Banner;
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    { 
       Test::get_banner_category();
       Banner::get_banner_category_all();
       // global scope
       /* or App\Models\Admin\Banner::get_banner_category_all(); */
    }
}
```